# Drupal Application Integration With Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, drupal

I am trying to setup one Drupal PHP Sample application which will be having Oracle DB as in backend. I have tried this URL

I have recently done all the changes like

I have recently done all the changes like

```
# cd includes/database/
# wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/oracle-7.x-1.12.tar.gz
    # tar -xzvf oracle-7.x-1.12.tar.gz
# rm oracle-7.x-1.12.tar.gz
# cd oracle/module/
# mv oracle/ /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/

(we still define our path to the root catalog of Drupal)

We set up the correct file admissions:

# cd /var/www/html/
# chown -R www-data:www-data ./
# chmod -R 750 ./
```

Enable below extensions as well

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll 
oci8.connection_class = Oracle
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

But it dint give any option of Oracle option while installing Drupal application. Can someone help me to achieve this application with oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is is a long process, but the following should get you started.

Drupal 8
https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle

https://drupalintegration.com/app/oracle-database

Drupal 7

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146300/is-it-possible-to-use-an-oracle-database-for-drupal-8/146307